# Flexural strength of 1x1 aluminum

Tags: structural-engineering, materials

Trying to build a rather odd tool box that will sit on the bed side of my truck and sue to a swinging arm with a pneumatic shock assist will lower and swing it outward till it hits a rubber stopper when it reaches my desired height. For now let’s say upright is 0° and lowered is 90°. My question is a 1”x1” 6063 aluminum tube with a .062 wall thickness that is 18” long and yield tensile strength of 21000 psi. If it is mounted on a hinge at the bottom and there is a rubber stopper to prevent it from going beyond 90° and be parallel with the ground and that stopper is coming in contact with the aluminum 2” from the hinge how much weight could it hold if there was one such system on each side of a box before flexural strength maxes out and the aluminum fails?